# Is there any way to inject MockBean inside another MockBean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mocking, spring-test

I have classes

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserService {
    private final WalletService walletService;

    public void increaseBalance() {
      walletService.increaseBalance();
    }
}

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WalletService {
    public void increaseBalance() {}
}
```

And test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest()
public class UserServiceTest {
  @MockBean
  private UserService userService;

  @Test
  public void testIncreaseBalance_realMethod() {
    //here I want to call real UserService method
    doCallRealMethod().when(userService).increaseBalance();

    userService.increseBalance();
  }

  @Test
  public void testIncreaseBalance_mockedMethod() {
    //here I don't want to call real UserService method

    userService.increseBalance();
  }

}
```

In this case **WalletService is not injected in UserService**. As I can see, the reason is that UserService is a @MockBean. Therefore, I have NullPointerException in test.

However, when I make UserService @SpyBean, WalletService is injected in UserService.

Is there any way to inject WalletService in UserService and still have it as @MockBean?

Comment: Do you want to test the behaviour of `UserService` itself, or do you need to test this with the complete application running?

Comment: I want to test UserService behavior with complete application running.
My main goal is to have flexibility with specifying whether I want to call real method of bean, or mock this method(as you can see in two test methods)

Comment: I would strongly advice not mixing that in a single test. A test using `@SpringBootTest` is normally an integration test that uses the actual beans. If you want to unit test the behaviour of `UserService`, then just manually create a mock of `WalletService` and pass it to the instance of `UserService` you also create manually.

Comment: I agree with you.
But imagine if I share same UserService object between multiple tests. 
I do it in order to keep the same ApplicationContext(because I have lots of tests and don't want to reload context on each test). 
In some tests I want UserService to act as mock and in other tests - to act as ordinary real object. Is there any way to do it without reloading ApplicationContext?

Comment: How could you test `UserService` class if you are mocking it?

Comment: It is possible to call real method with doCallRealMethod().when(userService).increaseBalance();

Comment: Almost everything is possible. My point is: if your `UserServiceTest` class aim is to test the `UserService` class, testing a mock of `UserService` class inside it is just an exercise. Isn't it?

Comment: Its just oversimplified version of what I want to do: share the same objects between classes. But in some test classes objects must be mocks and in other test classes they must be ordinary beans. I decided to do it to keep the same ApplicationContext between these test classes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the return value after the specified call method, when initiative is called, it will be intercepted by Mockito, return to your specified value, just as:

```java
Mockito.when(userService.increaseBalance()).thenReturn(1);
userService.increaseBalance() // print :1
```

Comment: Than you for your answer, but in this case I want to have flexibility with MockBean.
For instance, in first test method, I want to call real bean method.
And in second test method I want to mock bean method.

Comment: If you want to be true call, you need to be injected through the Spring container.For Mockito, he just intercepts back, you can take a look at his source code.